# Android React Native - Unable to press on TextInput field

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am working on an android app which contains a sidebar menu with a TextInput field at the top of it. My problem is that I cannot interact with it unless I enable autoFocus which is not what I wanted. Pressing on the TextInput on the UI does nothing right not. There are no issues on an iOS device. However, I am currently working on this for an Android version. (AVD Device: Pixel 3a, API 29enter image description here)

Some solutions I have tried:

- zIndex
- elevation
- setting TextInput height

Any help or suggestions to the solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a part of my code

```
const isRefreshing = this.props.refreshing['someData'] ? this.props.refreshing['someData'] : false;

...
<View style={someStyle}>
   <Image style={{ tintColor: '#777', width: 20, height: 20, resizeMode: 'contain' }]} source={SearchLogo}/>
      <TextInput
         style={[{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10, color: '#777' }, styles.fontDetail]}
         onChangeText={searchString => this.onSearchChangeText(searchString)}
         value={this.state.searchString}
         placeholder={'Type here to search...'}
         autoCapitalize={'none'}
         autoCompleteType={'off'}
         autoCorrect={false}
         autoFocus={false}
         clearButtonMode={'never'}
         returnKeyType={'search'}
         onSubmitEditing={this.onSearch}
         ref={searchInput => this.searchInput = searchInput}
         />}
</View>
...
```

Here is an image of the UI [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE75R.png)

Comment: Can I see full your code in Codepen? I will need to see full your code include your style

Comment: @NguyễnKhương https://codepen.io/jCincano/pen/wvgMQxy

Comment: Well, I was thinking about some absolute view bug in android but maybe it isn't the case. You might want to put some fixed width and height into your TextInput, the parent View of your TextInput and test again.
Also, turn on Inspectator in dev menu and find out where is it focus when you press on TextInput

Comment: I've already tried fixed height and width, but with no luck. Thank you for your suggestions. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I think the issue comes through the usage of gesture handler. Currently experiencing the same. I will update this once I found out more (or did you find already a solution?). My first naïve try was to use `TextInput` from gesture handler, but it didn't change anything…

Comment: No okay, sorry. In my case it was an absolute positioned invisible view above the other content that was capturing the press event.